# Set BITBUCKET_* variables for use inside an Electron Angular app

Tags: angular, electron, bitbucket, electron-builder, electron-updater

I have an Angular/Electron app running, which I want to auto-update itself. I have `electron-builder` working, it uploads the build files (`<name>.exe`, `<name>.blockmap` and `latest.yml`) without issue. But when I run the app on my Windows machine, `electron-updater` returns a 404 on the "latest.yml" file.

I've rested it directly with cURL and it works fine.

```
curl -L -H "Authorization: Basic <token>" https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<owner>/<repo>/downloads/latest.yml
```

The only different I can see is the `-L` switch which makes cURL follow redirects. Is this handled by `electron-updater`? Does it require some specific config for this to work properly?

Or maybe I'm doing the build wrong... I have the 2 `BITBUCKET_*` variables set on my build command. Should I expect the values to be built into the app? If not, what would be the best way to have those values set in the app without hardcoding them in the code?

Thanks!

UPDATE 1: I tried to put those variables in a `.env` file and include it in the build files list but it doesn't seem to be read when the app is run on the Windows machine.

UPDATE 2: I compiled the app as a Linux AppImage, then ran it from the command line while also setting the env variables in the command: `BITBUCKET_USERNAME=<user> BITBUCKET_TOKEN=<app-password> ./<name>.AppImage` but I'm also getting a 404 on the version update check. I see the variables as set if I log `process.env` to the console.

UPDATE 3: I even hardcoded the values in the entry script like so on the very first line, before require statements:

```
process.env.BITBUCKET_USERNAME = '<user>';
process.env.BITBUCKET_TOKEN = '<app-password>';
```

and still getting a 404.

SOLVED: Issue was an extra colon in the auth header.
`Basic: <token>` should've been `Basic <token>`.